# Remove Button and List value

Tags: angular

I have a list with values and buttons. I am trying to remove the button when the value is removed. My code will explain this better. Currently this is not happening. The value is removed but the delete button remains. Every time a value is added to the list a delete button is also added. When the value is removed I am not able to remove the delete button as well.

```
  <div *ngFor="let location of basics.locations; let index = index; trackBy: customTrackBy">
  <div  class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12 input-container">
    <label for="location1">Location {{index + 1}}*</label>
    <input [(ngModel)]="location.name" type="text" size="50" placeholder="Location" required>
    <span *checkIcon="location.name"></span>
  </div>

  <div class="ui-g-12 ui-md-12">
    <button type="button" (click)="deleteLocation(index)" class="add-location-btn btn btn-primary"> DELETE </button>
  </div>
  </div>

  deleteLocation(index) {
    this.basics.locations.splice(index, 1);
  }
```

Comment: Ok I have made a bad mistake. My array was not correct. The code above works. I am closing

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the problem is not in the code. It is a backend issue